# Create multi-projects with one solution

Tags: c#, wpf

I am a pretty know in WPF, I created three projects in one Solution, Example Project1, Project2 and Project3.

When I build solution, only Project1 that has it's own dll(Project1.dll), In Project3 need to use Project2.dll, but my Project2 and Project3 don't have it's own dll file, but in WinForm is okay.

My question is, why Project2 and Project3 don't have dll file like a Project1?

Thank in advance for any answer!

Comment: Maybe u forgot about adding references?

Comment: What type of project are Project1, Project2 and Project3?  You mention WinForms in your question, but you have tagged it WPF - which are you using? 




What type of project are Project1, Project2 and Project3?  You mention WinForms in your question, but you have tagged it WPF - which are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely that you don't have a reference added. For instance, Project1 is your startup WPF project and Project2 and Project3 are class library projects. Therefore if your Project1 does not have a reference to Project2 and Project3, the compiler will not create a corresponding dlls

Comment: So, how can Project1 reference to dll of Project2 and Project3?

Comment: Right-click on Project 1 and select Add References. Go to the Projects Tab and select the project name. You should be able to select both Projects at once and then click ok. The Project dll's should appear under references. For Reference and reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx

Comment: This will only work if Project2/3 are actually DLLs and not EXEs.  I'm not sure we've got enough information to be sure about this.  Besides, the compiler will still *build* the DLLs for all projects when building the solution; it just won't copy them to the Project1 output unless there's a reference.

Comment: (The question also states that Project1 *does* spit out a DLL, so it's unlikely that Project1 is the startup project.)

Comment: I don't know what happened, when I created second project(project2- WPF), and set Target framework: .Net Framework 4; Output type: class library, then I got error,After build solution!, what's wrong with this project?

Comment: what kind of error? Isn't it the case that the referenced project (Project2) has a higher version of .NET framework than the project referring to the the Project2?

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/mark as answered in case it was helpful.